# PipedInputStream together with TeeOutputStream freezes the application, when not read?

Tags: java, multithreading, io, freeze

PipedInputStream together with TeeOutputStream freezes the application, when not read!?

*I am referring to this `org.apache.commons.io.output.TeeOutputStream`. For easier testing, I added a simple variant of it as inner-class(`MyTeeOutputStream`) so you don't have to get the dependency.*

Any ideas why this happens and how I can fix it?

## Code

I made a JUnit5 test case for you guys to try out:

```java
    @Test
    void testSplittingOutput() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        PipedInputStream pipedInput = new PipedInputStream();
        OutputStream pipedOutput = new PipedOutputStream(pipedInput);
        //TeeOutputStream teeOutput = new TeeOutputStream(System.out, pipedOutput);
        MyTeeOutputStream teeOutput = new MyTeeOutputStream(System.out, pipedOutput);
        PrintStream out = new PrintStream(teeOutput);

        final int expectedPrintedLinesCount = 1000;
        AtomicInteger actualPrintedLinesCount = new AtomicInteger();
        
        Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> { // Thread for writing data to OUT
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < expectedPrintedLinesCount; i++) {
                    out.println("Hello! "+i);
                    actualPrintedLinesCount.incrementAndGet();
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });


        Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> { // Thread for reading data from IN
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pipedInput));
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                while(true){
                    builder.append(reader.readLine());
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //e.printStackTrace(); // ignore
                System.out.println(builder);
            }
        });

        t1.start();
        //t2.start(); // If we aren't reading then PipedInputStream in Thread2, we only print 94 lines instead of 1000!?

        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) { // 30 seconds max waiting for threads to complete
            Thread.sleep(1000); // Do this because Junit doesn't support multithreaded stuff
        }
        
        Assertions.assertEquals(expectedPrintedLinesCount, actualPrintedLinesCount.get()+1);
    }

final class MyTeeOutputStream extends OutputStream {

    private final OutputStream out;
    private final OutputStream tee;

    public MyTeeOutputStream(OutputStream out, OutputStream tee) {
        if (out == null)
            throw new NullPointerException();
        else if (tee == null)
            throw new NullPointerException();

        this.out = out;
        this.tee = tee;
    }


    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        out.write(b);
        tee.write(b);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(byte[] b) throws IOException {
        out.write(b);
        tee.write(b);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        out.write(b, off, len);
        tee.write(b, off, len);
    }

    @Override
    public void flush() throws IOException {
        out.flush();
        tee.flush();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        try {
            out.close();
        } finally {
            tee.close();
        }
    }
}
```

## Result

As you can see, it fails to print all lines (1000) and stops at (94):

```
Hello! 0
Hello! 1
Hello! 2
Hello! 3
Hello! 4
Hello! 5
Hello! 6
Hello! 7
Hello! 8
Hello! 9
Hello! 10
Hello! 11
Hello! 12
Hello! 13
Hello! 14
Hello! 15
Hello! 16
Hello! 17
Hello! 18
Hello! 19
Hello! 20
Hello! 21
Hello! 22
Hello! 23
Hello! 24
Hello! 25
Hello! 26
Hello! 27
Hello! 28
Hello! 29
Hello! 30
Hello! 31
Hello! 32
Hello! 33
Hello! 34
Hello! 35
Hello! 36
Hello! 37
Hello! 38
Hello! 39
Hello! 40
Hello! 41
Hello! 42
Hello! 43
Hello! 44
Hello! 45
Hello! 46
Hello! 47
Hello! 48
Hello! 49
Hello! 50
Hello! 51
Hello! 52
Hello! 53
Hello! 54
Hello! 55
Hello! 56
Hello! 57
Hello! 58
Hello! 59
Hello! 60
Hello! 61
Hello! 62
Hello! 63
Hello! 64
Hello! 65
Hello! 66
Hello! 67
Hello! 68
Hello! 69
Hello! 70
Hello! 71
Hello! 72
Hello! 73
Hello! 74
Hello! 75
Hello! 76
Hello! 77
Hello! 78
Hello! 79
Hello! 80
Hello! 81
Hello! 82
Hello! 83
Hello! 84
Hello! 85
Hello! 86
Hello! 87
Hello! 88
Hello! 89
Hello! 90
Hello! 91
Hello! 92
Hello! 93
Hello! 94
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :1000
Actual   :94
<Click to see difference>
```

## Details

**Why am I doing this?**
I want to duplicate the System.out and 'read' (through the PipedInputStream) from it, then send that data to my website's http console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that suited me the best:

## NonBlockingPipedInputStream

```java
public class NonBlockingPipedInputStream extends PipedInputStream {

    public interface WriteLineEvent<L>{
        void executeOnEvent(L l);
    }

    /**
     * Add actions to this list, which get run after a line has been written.
     * Contains the line as parameter.
     */
    public List<WriteLineEvent<String>> actionsOnWriteLineEvent = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

    /**
     *
     * Starts a new {@link Thread}, that reads the {@link PipedInputStream}
     * and fires an event every time a full line was written.
     * To listen for those events, add the action that should be run to the {@link #actionsOnWriteLineEvent} list.
     */
    public NonBlockingPipedInputStream() {
        new Thread(()->{
            try{
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this));
                String line;
                while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                    String finalLine = line;
                    actionsOnWriteLineEvent.forEach(action -> action.executeOnEvent(finalLine));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

## Usage

```java
    @Test
    void nonBlockingPipedInputStreamExample() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        NonBlockingPipedInputStream pipedInput = new NonBlockingPipedInputStream();
        OutputStream pipedOutput = new PipedOutputStream(pipedInput);
        MyTeeOutputStream teeOutput = new MyTeeOutputStream(System.out, pipedOutput);
        PrintStream out = new PrintStream(teeOutput);

        final int expectedPrintedLinesCount = 1000;
        AtomicInteger actualPrintedLinesCount = new AtomicInteger();
        AtomicInteger actualReadLinesCount = new AtomicInteger();

        Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> { // Thread for writing data to OUT
            try {
                for (int i = 1; i <= expectedPrintedLinesCount; i++) {
                    out.println("Hello! "+i);
                    actualPrintedLinesCount.incrementAndGet();
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        // NonBlockingPipedInputStream starts a new thread when it is initialised.
        // That thread reads the PipedInputStream and fires an event every time a full line was written.
        pipedInput.actionsOnWriteLineEvent.add(line -> {
            actualReadLinesCount.getAndIncrement();
        });

        t1.start();

        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) { // 30 seconds max waiting for threads to complete
            Thread.sleep(1000); // Do this because Junit doesn't support multithreaded stuff
        }

        Assertions.assertEquals(expectedPrintedLinesCount, actualPrintedLinesCount.get());
        Assertions.assertEquals(expectedPrintedLinesCount, actualReadLinesCount.get());
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

A `PipedInputStream` only has a buffer size of 1024 by default, so if you are adding to the PipedOutputStream without reading in your other thread it will block the writing until the buffer is emptied. That is why it stops at the 94th line of `Hello! XX\r\n`. 1024 divided by 11 means 93 full output lines are stored in `pipedInput`, and System.out works for 94th line but blocking on the pipedInput prevents more lines being added.

Comment: I guess I'll create a custom class that starts a new Thread and reads the PipedInputStream so that the buffer never gets full.

Comment: Yes - your choices are either you don't make the tee output, or add the tee with a background task to consume it just as you've shown in the commented out line - but better you replace the `while(true)` with proper End of File condition check.